# Contents of Tabhost getting reset after switching to 3rd tab

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Im developing an android app with 3 tabs. Once i'm done with fetching data from server i'm setting the text **Tab1 data set success** in 1st tab and new text is visible in the view. Then i switched to tab3 and switched back to tab1. Now the text is **Tab 1** which is defined in tab1.xml. So how can i retain previous views contents when i'm switching between  tabs.

My android code is below

```
public class secondPage  extends AppCompatActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String dateStrig = intent.getStringExtra("Date");
    String rData = null;
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("TAB 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    new fetchData().execute(dateStrig);


    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


}


public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(fetchData.class.getName());

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = new ProgressDialog(secondPage.this);
        progress.setMessage("loading...");
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String webPage = "", data = "";
        {

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.101:3000/rate?date=" + params[0]);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));


                while ((data = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    webPage += data + "\n";
                }

                logger.info(webPage);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        return webPage;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        TextView t1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t1.setText("Tab 1 selected");
             progress.dismiss();




    }


}
}
```

**PageAdapter.java**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

**Tab1.java**

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    }
}
```

**Tab2.java**

```
public class Tab2 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);
}
}
```

**Tab3.java**

```
public class Tab3 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);
    }
}
```

**main_screen.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
```

**tab1.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Tab 1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

tab2.xml and tab3.xml also looks same with different ID and text.

Comment: for what are you setting you page twice? remove viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

Comment: I'm doing it to show tab content if user clicks on tab name instead of swiping. After removing   **viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());** dint help.

Comment: ?? why not set viewpager? tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

Comment: tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);  wont change on swipe or tab select.I referred http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ during development.

Comment: try to implement using [this sample](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

This is because of offscreen behaviour of ViewPager. Default is 1 try to maximise this limit as per your requirement it works for me.

_pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using any caching techniques or using *FragmentPagerAdapter* instead of *FragmentStatePagerAdapter*. 
I don't prefer *FragmentPagerAdapter* solution because it will maintain the fragment in the memory which increase memory overheads if you get large data from the server.